# Android Billing. How to purchase multiple quantity of multiple items?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, google-play-billing

Do we have the possibility to purchase multiple different items with different quantity within a single purchase?

Sample:

- item_sku_0
- item_sku_1
- item_sku_2

The user selects

- item_sku_0 : qty: 3
- item_sku_1 : qty: 2
- item_sku_2 : qty: 4

the application combines the user cart into `List<BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams>` and then passes it to the library

```
val productDetailsParamsList = listOf<BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams>(
     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_0  */),
     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_0  */),
     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_0  */),

     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_1  */),
     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_1  */),

     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_2  */),
     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_2  */),
     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_2  */),
     ProductDetails(/* item_sku_2  */),
)


val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
     .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
     .build()
billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)
```

The Google Billing Library v6 demonstrates its native BottomSheet with `Error while retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01` error.

---

Is this feature able to be implemented based on the `Google Play Billing Library`?